# how to find the elements of additive Group - $\mathbb{Z_7^+}$

Tags: group-theory, problem-solving

I am given this additive Group G=$\mathbb{Z_7^+}$

I tried to find all its elements and I did:

$$gcd(1,7) = 1 \\ gcd(2,7) = 1 \\ gcd(3,7) = 1 \\ gcd(4,7) = 1 \\
gcd(5,7) = 1 \\ gcd(6,7) = 1 \\ gcd(7,7) = 7 \\ $$
Then I took all which gives $1$. so $1,2,3,4,5,6$ are all elements of this Group $G$. Am I right?

is it the only and good way of finding elements of given Group? regardless whether multiplicative or additive?

thanks a lot

Comment: You forgot the equivalence class of $0$.

Comment: do you mean the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_7$ or the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_7^{\times}$?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud, but I cannot do $gcd(0,7)$, how should I find $0$?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan, i mean $+$, additive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gcd is irrelevant when you are looking for elements of $\mathbb{Z}_7$. The elements of this group are in reality subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ : You say that two numbers $n$ and $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ are equivalent iff  $7\mid (n-m)$. Then equivalence class of $n$ is
$$
[n] = \{m \in \mathbb{Z} : 7\mid (n-m)\}
$$
This is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$. There are exactly 7 such subsets, because for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n$ is equivalent to its remainder upon division by 7. (For instance, $10$ is related to $3$, and so
$$
[10] = [3]
$$
The elements of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ are these equivalence classes
$$
\{[0], [1], \ldots, [6]\}
$$

Comment: thank you, finally, this was my problem, you hit the point! si gcd is irrelevant when it comes to additive groups, right?

Comment: For this additive group, yes. It is relevant when you are looking for elements in $\mathbb{Z}_7^{\times}$ though (which is why I asked my earlier question)

Comment: Ok, very nice. it was important thing to know. let me study your answer in detail now :))

Answer (score 1):

You actually take the modulus (ie $n \pmod 7$ ) for the additive method.  The multiplication group here consists of the 6 relatively primes to 7, which form a closed group to multiplication.

What happens in this sort of group is that if $m$ shares a common factor with $n$ it acts like a partial zero, destroying some information.  An example is in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, where one can easily construct $x$ from $3x$, but not from $2x$.

Comment: thanks wendy, so i should do like this: $ 1 mod 7, 2 mod 7 $ and then take those which give $1$ ?

Comment: or can i just count all the numbers till the upper border of Group, here $1,2,3,4,5,6$ ? whithout any algorithm

Comment: Taking all of the numbers from 0 to 6 will do the trick, since you are in effect using the test $0 \le x \lt n$ as your way of getting the set.

Comment: ok nice. thanks